# Manipulate and validate ConfigurationProperties value in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, configurationproperties

I have a configuration property:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "x.retention")
@Slf4j
@ConstructorBinding
@AllNonNullByDefault
@Validated
public class RetentionProperties {

  private String isoPeriod;

}
```

`isoPeriod` is going to be a period in iso8061 format like `P1M` -> 1 month duration.

I want to check if the value has a correct format on Configuration Initialisation.

Can I somehow also manipulate  the value on initialisation to transform it to Duration?
like this

`Duration duration = Duration.parse(isoPeriod);`

So that I can directly use the Duration value and not validate it later in code?

Comment: Spring Boot should automatically convert the value to a `Duration` afaik. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/convert/StringToDurationConverter.java (which is used to convert from properties to types during configuration loading).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type to `Duration`, Spring Boot will convert it to the proper `Duration` using the [`StringToDurationConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/convert/StringToDurationConverter.java).

Don't make it more complex then that.

Comment: Just changing the type doesn't seem to be enough: `java: incompatible types: java.time.Duration cannot be converted to java.lang.String`

Comment: For binding it is, then you must be using it elsewhere unless you are using some ancient version of Spring Boot that doesn't support this yet.